# TreeView change LeafNodeStyle.ImageUrl based on file extension

Tags: c#, treeview

I have an ASP:TreeView that I want to show on icon based upon the file extension. Here is my current code. I have also tried ondatabound using the same code but that does not work neither.

```
protected void MyTree_TreeNodeExpanded(object sender, TreeNodeEventArgs e)
{
    string fileExt = Path.GetExtension(e.Node.Selected.ToString());
    if (fileExt == ".pdf")
    {

      MyTree.LeafNodeStyle.ImageUrl = "/Images/icons/pdf_icon.png";
    }
    else
    {
      MyTree.LeafNodeStyle.ImageUrl = "/Images/icons/document_icon.png";
    }
}
```

The script above does not loop through the file structure. In the example below, the pdf file should have the pdf icon and the rest have the document icon.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Server.MapPath** specifies the relative or virtual path to map to a physical, but ImageUrl value must be absolute url or relative url.

You need to 
Replace

```
MyTree.LeafNodeStyle.ImageUrl = Server.MapPath("~/Images/icons/pdf_icon.png");
```

with

```
MyTree.LeafNodeStyle.ImageUrl = "/Images/icons/pdf_icon.png";
```

**Edit**

-`e.Node` return the expanded Node that is "Nursing" node in your example, but you need to loop through `e.Node.ChildNodes`.
 - `e.Node.Selected` Returns boolean value you should use `e.Node.Text` to get node text.
 - `MyTree.LeafNodeStyle.ImageUrl` changes all leafs style in tree so you need to change `ImageUrl` for every leaf.

this code must do the job.

```
    protected void MyTree_TreeNodeExpanded(object sender, TreeNodeEventArgs e)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < e.Node.ChildNodes.Count; i++)
        {
            if (e.Node.ChildNodes[i].ChildNodes.Count != 0)
                continue;
            string fileExt = Path.GetExtension(e.Node.ChildNodes[i].Text);

            if (fileExt == ".pdf")
            {
                e.Node.ChildNodes[i].ImageUrl = "/Images/icons/pdf_icon.png";
            }
            else
            {
                e.Node.ChildNodes[i].ImageUrl = "/Images/icons/document_icon.png";
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: I added more information to explain the question better